# Filtering an array of objects by class not working

Tags: arrays, swift, class, filter

I have a `UIStackView` that contains `UIView`s or objects of a class I have created called `MyView`.

`MyView` is a subclass of `UIView`.

I want to extract from that array, all objects of class `MyView`.

This is what I have tried and the respective errors:

```
let views = Array< MyView >(allViews).filter { $0 is MyView }
```

> type of expression is ambiguous without more context

I love these messages that say nothing.

```
let views = Array<Any>(allViews).filter { $0 is MyView }
```

I love how this compiles with `Any`.

No error in this case, but `views` contains the same objects as `myViews`, nothing is being filtered.

I understand that `MyView` is a subclass of `UIView`, so what swift is testing here is if the object is of class `UIView`. If this is true, why bothering allowing programmers to specify any class on the filter, if it can only filter some classes?

Is there a way to test for subclasses?

Comment: What is `allViews` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `allViews` is an array of `UIView`.

You should use `compactMap`, which will map to an array of the subclass, throwing away any `nil` values (which result from the `as?`):

```
let views = allViews.compactMap { $0 as? MyView }
```

Note here `views` is already of type `[MyView]`; take a look at `compactMap`'s method signature to understand:

```
func compactMap<ElementOfResult>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult]
```

Comment: Brilliant, your code works. I had a typo here. Thanks.